# Failed to build cause of Incompatibilite with version of firebase and camera react native

Tags: java, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-camera

Here is what im using :

```
"react": "16.8.3",
"react-native": "0.59.10",
"react-native-camera": "3.3.0",
"react-native-firebase": "5.5.6"
```

I need `react-native-camera` for scanning barcode, but when i try to add `react-native-firebase` but its failed to build. but, its only failed on Android, on IOS its working perfectly.

this what i've try to solve this : 
1. Re-install Package RNFirebase and re-link the package using automatic or manual
2. I have try to add this on gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

3. I have try to downgrading version but it doesnt help.
4. i have try to add this too in Manifest, but it give me more error duplicate.

```
tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"
android:appComponentFactory="whateverString"
```

this what error said on terminal :

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

  > Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86
  >       is also present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91 value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory).
  >       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:appComponentFactory"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

im expecting to build react-native with both camera and firebase.

also i have ask to the community, but no answer yet.
https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2486

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to upgrade react-native-camera, I'm using 3.11.1 with firebase 5.5.6 and all is working fine